# Spring Boot not returning correct MIME type

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a Spring MVC app with Spring boot, Spring Security and Thymeleaf.

The problem is - when i'm requesting a page with it's html and css, i'm not getting the correct MIME type for my css file, thus why Chrome cannot load it with status "**canceled**" and the message "**Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/login' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.**"

I'm linking the css file correctly: 
" "

The css file is contained in:

resources -> static -> css - > style.css

I've allowed all resouces from the resources folder in the Security config file:

```
    package org.isp.configuration;

import org.isp.services.api.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider
                = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(getBCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        String[] permitted = new String[]{
                "/", "/home","/register","/about","/png/**",
                "/css/**","/icons/**","/img/**","/js/**","/layer/**"
        };

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(permitted).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/unauthorized")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder getBCryptPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

This is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
         xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" >
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        **<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css" type="text/css">**
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:include="~{fragments/navbar :: navbar}"></div>

        <div class="container">
            <h3>Home</h3>
            <p>This is the home page of the project!</p>
        </div>

        <div th:include="~{fragments/footer :: footer}" class="footer"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any ideas how can i fix the incorrect MIME type? Is there any configuration im missing?

Answer (score 13):

I've just been struggling with the same issue, and I finally realized that it was a red herring - the real problem was `404`, and the MIME type error came from Spring's handling of it. As explained in the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling), its built-in error handling automatically redirects to `/error` and outputs the error details as JSON. When I checked my logs, I saw a `404` in my webserver access log and the following in my application log:

```
DEBUG DispatcherServlet:869 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:310 - Looking up handler method for path /error
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:317 - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
DEBUG HttpEntityMethodProcessor:234 - Written [{timestamp=Fri Apr 06 14:06:54 PDT 2018, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available, path=/css/style.css}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@5ef96137]
```

So, your real problem is that Spring is not finding your static resources. You'll want to make sure the `resources` folder is in your classpath, or explicitly set the locations using the `spring.resources.static-locations` property.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I have to permit requests for static files to get it to work.

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Overide
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have used additional filter. So all kind of request will go through that filter. even css and js file used to go through that.

At this point, for some request in the ratio of 1/7 or 1/10, I get mime type issue, for css file the server returns with the type of application/javascript or application/json and ect.

Then I used **@WebFilter** and allows only api request to go through that filter.

**@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/api/*")**

Now the css and js files not allowed in that additional filter. and then I did't find issue with mime type.

In my point of view, when we have too many filters the backend fails to handle frequent request for resources (js, css, img ...), So it returns with wrong MIME type.

Hope, this would help someone, who face this kind of issue

Answer (score 0):

A client had the case today (24 nov 2021) when Spring Security was redirecting most of the requested urls to "/login" equivalent functional endpoint. No assets were loaded, and the same message you get about mimetype was in their Google Chrome console logs.

Diagnostic was done with entering the assets with wrong mimetype and see the loading of the "/login" endpoint.

It was resolved with adding some Spring Security mapping rules in their SecurityConfig.class of their Spring Boot Application, so the webapp is running well now.