# Some CSS files require "text/css" while some require "stylesheet/css" types

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'll probably be ripped to shreds for this question, but here we go.

We've all seen the dreadful:

```
Refused to apply style from <URL> because its MIME type <TYPE> is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Its origin and fix are typically project-oriented, and countless answers on StackOverflow offer countless solutions, many of which can't be applied generically. Here's a peculiar situation, which I can't seem to wrap my head around, given that I mainly work on the back-end:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/real-fun/css/stylesheet.css}">
<link type="stylesheet/css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/real-fun/css/tail.select-light.css}">
```

I'm using Thymeleaf as the templating/server-side rendering engine of choice. While not perfect, it does the job for me - hence the `th:href` attributes instead of regular ones, and the `@{}` syntax.

Here's the thing - the first file has to be loaded as `"text/css"` otherwise, the browser refuses to apply its style, while the second file has to be loaded as `"stylesheet/css"`, otherwise the browser blocks that.

In both cases, it claims that the files are of `"application/json"` type, and none of them are.

In this scenario, the first one won't load, but the second one will:

```
<link type="stylesheet/css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="...">
<link type="stylesheet/css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="...">
```

In this scenario, the second one won't load, but the first one will:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="...">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="...">
```

What gives and how do I figure out which MIME type is expected *before* the browser gets a stroke?

Comment: The mime type comes from how the server delivers the file, not from the `<link>` tag. `rel=stylesheet` is all you need if the server is properly configured. Use your browser's "Network" developer tool to look at what the HTTP responses look like for stylesheets that are not working.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks for the tip! I'll check it out and get back to you. :)

Comment: @admcfajn - the paths are correct. That's a common issue in most questions/answers. This one has nothing to do with the path - they both load correctly using the same path. The only variable that changes is the `rel` attribute.

Comment: Thanks yeah, re-read your question & saw the @{} ... I'm 99.9% sure that `stylesheet/css` is invalid & it should always be `text/css`. Wild guess: what happens if you change `tail.select-light.css` to `tail-select-light.css`?

Comment: @admcfajn Same result, it's refusing to apply the style from an `"application/json"` MIME type :(

Comment: For that file, (/real-fun/css/tail.select-light.css) like Pointy mentions, you'll want to checkout the network tab & hit refresh then look for that file & checkout the response. It sounds like [this question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095234/spring-boot-not-returning-correct-mime-type). The application/json response is likely an error page. I'm more of a PHP person than a Java person, but does Springboot sound familiar? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-web-applications.spring-mvc.error-handling

Comment: @Pointy So, both files are being served by the same endpoint, on the same server, but one's working and one's not. This is mildly infuriating...

Comment: @admcfajn Yup, using Spring Boot :)

Comment: Just managed to fix it, posted the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have no idea why or how this fixed anything, but it did.

There was a file, dubbed `tail-select.js`, which imported `tail.select.js`. These are two distinct files and `tail.select.js` is the actual JS file for the library.

Even though `tail.select.js` didn't depend on `tail-select.js` - this import *somehow* affected it. After deleting the `tail-select.js` file, which seems to have erroneously made its way into the project - the CSS file loads just right, via `rel="text/css"`.

I fail to understand how an off-shoot JS file importing another file and not doing anything with it managed to break the imported file, and furthermore - how this changed the way the CSS file is loaded. Nevertheless, it's (somehow) working now and I'm afraid to ask any more questions.